# Not Able to access $scope outside the function

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a function called getMail()

```
$scope.getMail=function(){
  $http.get(APISource).
    success(function(data) {



  $scope.mail =data;



}).
error(function(data) {
    console.log("error");
  console.log(data);

});


}
```

in the success of this function i am saving the return data in $scope.mail;
and also i have another function

> function1() in the same controller but $scope.mail is not accessible.

please help.

Comment: `mail` could be undefined since `$get` is an async call...when do you call function1?

Comment: after calling getMail()

Answer (score 2):

`$http.get` is performed asynchronously. This means that the setting of `$scope.mail` happens in a separate thread, and will most likely not be available in the same thread after calling the $http.get.

A possible solution could be to move everything you want to do with `$scope.mail` into the body of the `success()` callback:

```
...
success(function(data) {
  $scope.mail =data;
  function1();
})
...
```

Comment: are u able to make a fiddle?

Comment: @NishamMahsin I added a code example. I don't see what a snippet would contribute to explaining this.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a fiddle that takes a few liberties to get something up and running grabbing fake data (from jsFiddle's api): http://jsfiddle.net/jetweedy/8vxvfcf7/

```
var app = angular.module('app', []);
app.controller('PhoneListCtrl', function ($scope, $http) {
    $scope.getMail = function () {
        $http.get("/echo/json/").
        success(function (data) {
            $scope.mail = data;
            console.log("success", $scope.mail);   
            $scope.function1();
        }).
        error(function (data) {
            console.log("error", data);
        });
    }
    $scope.function1 = function() {
        console.log("function1", $scope.mail);   
    }
    $scope.getMail();
});
```